# Application of derivatives (inequality, differentiable point)

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't get this solution.

1. Why is the inequality for f(x) not have equal signs on all of them? For example, x <= -4 for x^2-16 gives the same answer as 16-x^2. Is this some kind of mathematical rule or just a preference, meaning you can put the equal to or less/bigger sign anywhere you want?
2. Why would -4 and 4 be critical points? I know by definition critical points is where f'(c) = 0 or f'(c) does not exist. Clearly the right hand inequalities imply 4 is not in f'(x), hence it isn't differentiable at 4. But why would 4 be undifferentiable if it is in the domain of the original function f(x)? I think this is related to my first question and its very confusing to me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Critical points are points where the derivative is zero OR undefined. If you look at the piece wise inequalities for the derivative you can see that $-4$ and $4$ are not in the domain. This makes sense, as piece wise functions tend to be "sharp", like $|x|$, and the "sharp" points are not differentiable.  For example $|x|$ is defined for all real numbers, but  its derivative is not defined for $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point 1. Not, this is not a rule, it's the definition of the function!, and as it's continuous $$\lim_{x\to4^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to4^{-}} f(x).$$

And as you conjectured, point 1. and 2. are related. You function is CONTINUOUS in all it's domain since
$$\lim_{x\to y^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to y^{-}} f(x), \qquad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}m $$ BUT, it's not SMOOTH, that means you may have point we the derivative on the left is different from the one on the right. For your function $f(x)$, we have $$\lim_{x\to \pm4^{+}} f'(x) = - \lim_{x\to \pm 4^{-}} f'(x)$$. Therefore they are not differentiable at that points, thus 4 and $-4$ are critical points of $f(x)$.